# Navbar link color change on click

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm using the latest version of Bootstrap 3.

Inside my navbar I have:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topnav-navbar">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="http://localhost/anything">Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to change navbar background colour and link colour.

I've created the following Sass code (SCSS syntax).

```
.navbar {    
  background: #2C3E50;
  .navbar-nav li a {
    color: #eee;
    &:hover {
      color: #18BC9C;
    }
  }
}
```

It's working almost fine, but when I click on link (not on hover) for a split second I'm getting my link in gray colour with border/box shadow (on hover and on out everything looks as it should).

The question is - what class to use to remove border/shadow and use colour I defined? I've tried a while and achieved nothing. It's really hard for me to guess what class to use to achieve effect I want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to include `:focus` and `:active` too like this:

```
.navbar {    
  background: #2C3E50;
  .navbar-nav li a {
    color: #eee;
    &:hover, &:focus, &:active {
      color: #18BC9C;
      background-color: transparent;
      -webkit-box-shadow: none;
      -moz-box-shadow: none;
      box-shadow: none;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Thanks,  `&:hover,  &:focus, &:active { color: #18BC9C; box-shadow: none;}` instead of `&:hover {color: #18BC9C;}` seems to do the trick

Comment: After searching everywhere you saved my sunday!